# Check if wp-login is current page

Tags: pages, login, user-registration, conditional-tags

How can I check if the current page is `wp-login.php` or `wp-signup.php` ?

Are there more elegant solutions than using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` ?

Comment: For reference there is related trac discussion here https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/19898

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Use the global `$pagenow`, which is a common global set by WordPress at runtime:

```
if ( $GLOBALS['pagenow'] === 'wp-login.php' ) {
    // We're on the login page!
}
```

You can also check the *type* of login page, for example registration:

```
if ( $GLOBALS['pagenow'] === 'wp-login.php' && ! empty( $_REQUEST['action'] ) && $_REQUEST['action'] === 'register' ) {
    // We're registering
}
```

**Following code is considered legacy and should not be used** (`wp-register.php` was deprecated & subsequently removed quite a while back):

```
if ( in_array( $GLOBALS['pagenow'], array( 'wp-login.php', 'wp-register.php' ) ) )
    run_my_funky_plugin();
```

Comment: Does this works if user change his wp-login.php url?

Comment: Good question from @LucasBustamante and I suppose it's easily tested. It's just very important to point out and save someone time.

Comment: @T.Todua has provided a safer and more reliable answer [below](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/237285/60036).

Comment: For me even pagenow says it's index.php ...

Answer (score 24):

## My preferred way:

```
if( is_wplogin() ){
   ...
}
```

code:

```
function is_wplogin(){
    $ABSPATH_MY = str_replace(array('\\','/'), DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, ABSPATH);
    return ((in_array($ABSPATH_MY.'wp-login.php', get_included_files()) || in_array($ABSPATH_MY.'wp-register.php', get_included_files()) ) || (isset($_GLOBALS['pagenow']) && $GLOBALS['pagenow'] === 'wp-login.php') || $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']== '/wp-login.php');
}
```

## Why it's safest?

1. Sometimes, if you try to check login page using `REQUEST_URI`(or `SCRIPT_PATH`), you will get INCORRECT VALUES, because many plugins change **LOGIN & ADMIN** urls.

   2) `$pagenow` will give you incorrect value too in that case!

## Notes:

- In some cases, it might not work if you output login-form (i.e. with shortcode or etc) manually on other template files/pages.

## Core Update:

Since WordPress Version 6.1 (Nov 2022) is an additional function inside the core - [`is_login`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_login/) that check the `wp_login_url`.

Comment: This is fantastic. Using included files to determine a visitor location isn't a scenario I've ever found myself doing but it makes sense in this case.

Comment: @RyanBayne thnx, yes, this is the rare occasion when `get_included_files()` seems most accurate solution (at lest for me).

Comment: For me it returns false, as if it was not a wp-login page ... Also even $GLOBALS['pagenow'] returns index.php ...

Comment: @trainoasis probably you are using manual login-form (like shortcode) on homepage or like that?

Comment: No, normal wp-login.php :) But I am using Sage and WooCommerce, maybe that changes things somehow :)

Comment: This is the answer.

Answer (score 8):

There is a new function introduced in WordPress 6.1.0 which is `is_login()` which does just that.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_login/

Answer (score 5):

More modern way to do that, it should work even when the wp-login URL is changed by plugins and when WP is in a subfolder, etc:

```
if(stripos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"], strrchr(wp_login_url(), '/')) !== false){
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: I was going to suggest that. Maybe the OP needs parse the results from wp_login_url() and oly compare the web path.

Comment: I like this answer the best. To fit my preferences, I tweaked it slightly to: `return false !== stripos( wp_login_url(), $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] );`. That feels a bit cleaner to me.

Answer (score 2):

`$GLOBALS['pagenow']` doesn't work, use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`.

```
if ( in_array( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], array( '/wp-login.php', '/wp-register.php' ) ) ){
    // do something.
}
```

and if your wordpress is not installed in the web root folder, you should use some params like `YOUR_WP_PATH/wp-login.php` to replace the elements in array.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more readable version of @T.Todua answer. I just formatted it nicely, made the cheapest checks first and returned early:

```
function isLoginPage()
{
    // $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] is equal to "/wp-login.php"?
    if ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/wp-login.php') {
        return true;
    }

    // $GLOBALS['pagenow'] is equal to "wp-login.php"?
    if (isset($GLOBALS['pagenow']) && $GLOBALS['pagenow'] === 'wp-login.php') {
        return true;
    }


    $ABSPATH_MY = str_replace(array('\\', '/'), DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, ABSPATH);

    // Was wp-login.php or wp-register.php included during this execution?
    if (
        in_array($ABSPATH_MY . 'wp-login.php', get_included_files()) ||
        in_array($ABSPATH_MY . 'wp-register.php', get_included_files())
    ) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

If you want the least performance impact, leave only the first two checks.

Also, if you are running this check after the template has loaded, you can simply use:

```php
function isLogin() {
    if (!did_action('wp_loaded')) {
      return null;
    }
    return did_action('login_head');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented it using WordPress own wp_login_url() method as follows:

```
public static function is_wp_login() {
  $login_path = rtrim( strtolower( parse_url( wp_login_url( '', true ), PHP_URL_PATH ) ), '/' );
  return ( rtrim( strtolower( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ] ), '/' ) == $login_path );
}
```

Just comparing both paths (because it's difficult to be absolutely sure about the use of SSL as it may be terminated) should be enough ... It does mean, however, that a plugin or theme developer who changes the default login form must have done so the proper way ...

Comment: To ignore url params, change the last line to: return substr(rtrim( strtolower( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ] ), '/' ), 0, strlen($login_path)) == $login_path ;

Answer (score 1):

None of the current answers worked for me.

What I've done was check if `$_GET` array has a 'page' key and if its value is 'sign-in'.

```php
if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'sign-in'){
   // you're on login page
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to add some code for login page, you can use a hook for it

```
<?php add_action( 'login_head', 'login_head_add_css' );
    function login_head_add_css() {
        ?>
        <style>
            body {
                background-image: url('/background.png');
            }
            .login h1 a{
                background-image: url('/logo.png');
                background-size: 300px !important;
                background-position: center top;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                color: #444;
                height: 120px;
                font-size: 20px;
                font-weight: 400;
                line-height: 1.3;
                margin: 0 auto 25px;
                padding: 0;
                text-decoration: none;
                width: 300px !important;
                text-indent: -9999px;
                outline: 0;
                overflow: hidden;
                display: block;
            }

        </style>
        <?php
    } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This file has so many [action](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/actions/) hooks. Thanks WordPress devs!

Here's a listing of the most common ones to get you started in the order they execute.

- login_enqueue_scripts
- login_head
- login_header
- login_init
- login_form_{$action}

  - confirm_admin_email
  - postpass
  - logout
  - lostpassword
  - retrievepassword
  - resetpass
  - rp
  - register
  - login
  - confirmaction
- login_form
- login_footer

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method:

```
/**
 * Determines whether current page is login page.
 * @return bool True if current page is login page.
 */
final public static function isLoginPage(): bool
{
    return function_exists('login_header');
}
```

Function `login_header` is defined in file **wp-login.php**. We are assuming, that login page is not included as this is separate WP page, which shall be called directly. Probably one of the most bulletproof solutions.

Answer (score 1):

This is my preferred method, it will handle any slug you decide to use for the login page.  It also handles custom login forms if you decide not to use the default WordPress login form since is_login() won't work if you don't include the login script.  Uses global $wp instead of the $_SERVER array.

```
global $wp;

if( trailingslashit( trailingslashit( site_url() ) . $wp->request ) !== wp_login_url() ) {
    // You are on the login page
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am only interested in register page, not in login page. So this might not be wanted by everybody.

$GLOBALS['pagenow'] returns index.php for me. Maybe because of buddypress or my theme.

So I used

```
is_page('register')
```

If you inspect the body of the registration page, it also has the ID as well, so if it says *page-id-4906*, you can use it this way if it works better:

```
is_page('4906')
```

Comment: This is only valid if a plugin is modifying the default login.

Answer (score 0):

Always a good idea to use WP native function `is_login()`. This is introduced since 6.1.

[Here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_login/) is the details

Comment: That was already mentioned in https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/411320/3898 and https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/237285/3898. Redundant answers make it harder to use the site, so I'd recommend deleting this.