# Wordpress redirect to landing page if not logged in

Tags: php

I'm using the following code in my functions.php file to redirect users who are not logged in to a particular landing page

```
    <?php
if(!is_user_logged_in()) {
    wp_redirect( 'http://www.mysite.com/landingpage', 301 ); exit;
}
```

The problem is I cannot access my wp-login or wp-admin anymore. Every url redirects to landingpage. Is there a way I can exclude certain urls from redirecting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

something like:

```
if (
  !in_array($GLOBALS['pagenow'], array('wp-login.php', 'wp-register.php'))
  && !is_admin()
  && !is_user_logged_in()
) {
  wp_redirect('http://www.mysite.com/landingpage', 301);
  exit;
}
```

should do it.

see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin & 
[Check if wp-login is current page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12863/check-if-were-on-the-wp-login-page)

Comment: Thanks for the response. This looks like it will do the trick but I'm getting a syntax error on line 5. Any ideas?

Comment: yeah, sorry. missed the brackets.

Comment: which brackets?

Comment: i already edited the answer. the ones behind is_user_logged_in where initially missing... was that it?

Comment: No, still getting the error on line 5

Comment: line2 was also missing a bracket at the end.... (edited)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '.../' || $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '.../'){

   if(!is_user_logged_in()) {
       wp_redirect( 'http://www.mysite.com/landingpage', 301 ); exit;
   }
}
```

This basically tests to see if you are on a specific page, before executing the redirect, if the first statement returns true, and the user is not logged in it will redirect.

Comment: if i used this condition then i got "Warning: Cannot modify header information" message.