# WordPress 302 Redirect to Holding Page

Tags: redirect, htaccess

Once again struggling with htaccess. I've successfully redirected the home page to my holding page with the following rule but it's not applying to child pages for some reason (mydomain.com/child-page).

```
# MAINTENANCE-PAGE REDIRECT
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/holding [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif|eot|svg|ttf|woff|css) [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /holding [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

What am I doing wrong? I know it must be to do with the '^(.*)$' bit but I can;t seem to find the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would place the redirect inside WordPress. It lends you more control, and you don't need to worry about WP conflicting with your own `.htaccess` rewrites anymore.

```
function wpse_147377_redirect_to_holding() {
    if ( ! is_page( 'holding' ) ) {
         wp_redirect( site_url( 'holding' ) );
         exit;
    }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse_147377_redirect_to_holding' );
```

Place it in a "Must Use" plugin (`wp-content/mu-plugins/my-plugin.php`), a regular plugin, or your theme's `functions.php`.

Comment: I'm not sure about this one @TheDeadMedic: it creates a redirect loop when I use it. Should it take that condition into account automatically? Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I assumed your holding page was outside WP - you're right, just add `if ( ! is_page( 'holding' ) )` and change the hook to `template_redirect` (see edit).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks for pointing me in the right direction @TheDeadMedic. I found a tidy conditional on [this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75349/landing-page-redirect-loop) which works like a charm with the added benefit of checking to see if the user is logged in.

```
if ( trim( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/' ) != 'holding' && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    wp_redirect( home_url( 'holding' ), 302 );
    exit;
}
```