# Redirect if not logged in?

Tags: functions, wp-redirect

I've tried this to redirect people who aren't logged in to certain page. It ultimately shouldn't matter what front end page they visit, but should redirect to whatever page is chosen as the landing page (which I'm assuming would be the URL in the wp_redirect). I still need access to wp-login and dashboard etc...

I placed the following code in my functions.php, but did not work.

```
function my_redirect() {    
   if ( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == 'mybigfatsite.com/' ) {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
       wp_redirect( 'mybigfatsite.com/landing/' );
       exit;
    }
}
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_redirect' );
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `HTTP_HOST` typically doesn't contain `http://`, do some debugging to figure out what you're actually trying to match.

Comment: Thanks Milo. Perhaps my question - or my knowledge! - isn't clear, I'm pretty "green". I did remove the http:// from the above code and the home page redirects to the landing page, but I'd like all pages to redirect to the landing page. I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `is_login_page()` function is taken from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12863/check-if-were-on-the-wp-login-page)

```
function is_login_page() {
    if ( $GLOBALS['pagenow'] === 'wp-login.php' && ! empty( $_REQUEST['action'] ) && $_REQUEST['action'] === 'register' )
        return true;
    return false;
}

function my_redirect() {  
    //if you have the page id of landing. I would tell you to use if( is_page('page id here') instead
    //Don't redirect if user is logged in or user is trying to sign up or sign in
    if( !is_login_page() && !is_admin() && !is_user_logged_in()){
        //$page_id is the page id of landing page
        if( !is_page($page_id) ){
            wp_redirect( get_permalink($page_id) );
            exit;
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_redirect' );
```

Comment: this gives me the following: In Chrome "This page has a redirect loop" and in Safari "Too many redirects occurring..."

Comment: @leftside Stupid mistake on my part. Try it now.

Comment: thanks sakiboom. I kept getting redirects, but I changed your code to wp_redirect('/landing'); and now it sort of works - except I still need access to the login page and admin area. I've edited my question.

Comment: @leftside It should work now.

Comment: ack! You've been so helpful so far - I hate to say that this puts me back in the redirect loop.

Comment: Try adding this action to the `template_redirect` hook instead of `init`.

Comment: @leftside Works for me. My suggestion would be to use `is_page($page_id)` approach as that's more robust. Check my edit.

Comment: @cfx, that did the trick! And thanks sakibmoon for the bulk of the answer and so much help! So I'm unsure what to do now: accept this as the answer? Wait till it's updated?

Comment: @leftside updated just now. Be sure to use `is_page()` rather than SERVER variables. It will save you from tons of problem later.