# Allow the access over wp-login.php

Tags: functions, templates, redirect, maintenance

I created a maintenace template, and redirected to the folder where it is located via the functions.php file inside the theme folder;

this is the code:

```
function maintenance_redirect(){
if( !is_user_logged_in()){
  include("maintenance/index.html");
            exit();
}
    }
add_action( 'init' ,'maintenance_redirect' );
```

but i can't access to the log in page via wp-login.php or wp-admin/ beacause i get redirected to the maintenance page, how can i esclude from redirection the path of log in page?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if we're on the wp-login page?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12863/check-if-were-on-the-wp-login-page)

Comment: See also related trac discussion: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/19898

Comment: Is there any particular reason you didn't use the built in maintenance mode and template, or one of the maintenance mode plugins?

Comment: @TomJNowell more than a maintenance template, the template is for a preview, before the site is open to the public, so I prefer to use a custom one

Comment: @StephenHarris Thank you very much for the solutions, I see right away if they do in my case

Comment: I tried to use the function is-login () but It combines the maintenance template with the blog, could you give me some advice on how to better integrate it with the main code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the hook `template_redirect` instead - this will ensure it only runs on the front-end of your site, and not for the admin, login, registration or signup pages.

```
function wpse_159552_maintenance() {
    if ( ! is_front_page() ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
        exit;
    }

    include 'maintenance/index.html';
    exit;
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse_159552_maintenance' );
```

Comment: it works :D, but it shows the full url redirection, there's a way to stay only in domain.com?

Comment: Of course (see revision). But I don't think it's necessary for a maintenance page.

Comment: tried, but if i try to login via wp-login.php i get redirected again

Comment: Do you add the code I provided to the `template_redirect` hook?

Comment: sure, but it redirects me again to the homepage, maybe could try the hook template_include

Comment: See my revised answer. Any request that isn't for the admin or login pages will be redirected to the front page and shown the maintenance page. Is that the functionality you're after?

Comment: yes exactly. but it redirects me to the homepage, to specify that, I put the code in the functions.php file of the wp theme, maybe I should put it somewhere else?

Comment: `functions.php` is fine. So is it working as intended or do you not want the redirect?

Comment: I would like access to wordpress, but I get redirected to the maintenance page...

Comment: My code won't affect `/wp-admin/` or `wp-login.php` -  are you using any other plugins that might be interfering?

Comment: ok, I try to delete all redirect plugins

Comment: were those that interfered, thank you very much for your help :D