# How to change the wp-login.php page title?

Tags: php, filters, login

I've been using the `document_title_parts` hook to change the page title for some front end pages. However, this doesn't seem to work for the login, register and password management pages.

How can I change the wp-login.php page `<title>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like it's not easily accessible as it's displayed as <sup>[src](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/1d34043e8cd2eead37048bc8aed379d57ff32408/wp-login.php#L69)</sup>:

```
<title><?php echo get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) . $separator . $title; ?></title>
```

where the separator is:

```
    $separator = is_rtl() ? ' &rsaquo; ' : ' &lsaquo; ';
```

and the `$title` part comes from:

```
login_header( $title = 'Some title' , ... );
```

But it looks like you've already checked this out, as I see you've filed a ticket [#40812](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/40812) for an extra filter to change the *separator*.

A workaround that comes to mind, to change the *separator*, would be to use *output buffering* hacks to replace it.

Comment: I did notice the separator wasn't filterable a few weeks back. I hadn't thought of output buffering; I think that's the only solution until #40812 is implemented.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this code in your themes functions.php

```
function custom_login_title( $login_title ) {
return str_replace(array( ' &lsaquo;', ' &#8212; WordPress'), array( ' &bull;', ' what ever you want'),$login_title );
}
add_filter( 'login_title', 'custom_login_title' );
```

This will change the login.php `<title>` to Log In • Blog Name what every you want

You can do the same for all admin pages but it would be `$admin_title` instead of `$login_title`

Comment: It worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

### The problem

As @birgire pointed out, changing the title text on `wp-login.php` is not easily doable, since we don't have the various title altering filters like the front end offers.

### A solution

However, we can detect if we're on `wp-login.php` and then determine which action the user is taking: logging in, registering, or resetting their password.

The `<title>` tag on `wp-login.php` is made up of three parts:

```
<title><?php echo get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) . $separator . $title; ?></title>
```

We can alter the `get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' )` and `$title` areas but unfortunately, `$separator` can not be changed with the technique outlined here.

The `option_{option_name}` filter ( `option_blogname` in this case ) can be used to modify the `get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' )` part of the title.

The `$title`, is passed to `__()` which means that we can intercept it and change it using the `gettext` filter.

`$title` is assigned `__('Log In')`, `__('Registration Form')`, and `__('Lost Password')` on the log in, register, and lost password pages respectively.

### The code

This code will wire up the appropriate filters on `wp-login.php` for both of the changeable parts of the title.

```
/**
 * Detect if we're on wp-login.php and wire up the appropriate filters
 * based on what action being taken by the user.
 * idea via https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/12865/2807
 */
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_login_register_password_title' );
function wpse_login_register_password_title() {

    if ( isset( $GLOBALS['pagenow'] ) && $GLOBALS['pagenow'] === 'wp-login.php' ) {

        // Registration
        if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['action'] ) && $_REQUEST['action'] === 'register' ) {
            add_filter( 'option_blogname', 'wpse_login_page_register_blogname', 10, 1 );
            add_filter( 'gettext', 'wpse_login_page_register_title', 10, 3 );
        }

        // Password
        else if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['action'] ) && $_REQUEST['action'] === 'lostpassword' ) {
            add_filter( 'option_blogname', 'wpse_login_page_password_blogname', 10, 1 );
            add_filter( 'gettext', 'wpse_login_page_password_title', 10, 3 );
        }

        // Log in
        else {
            add_filter( 'option_blogname', 'wpse_login_page_blogname', 10, 1 );
            add_filter( 'gettext', 'wpse_login_page_title', 10, 3 );
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the filters that will modify the blogname portion of the title tag for each of the `wp-login.php` actions.

```
/**
 * Change get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) portion of the <title>'s
 * text on the wp-login.php page.
 * Immediately remove the filters so that they only run once.
 */
function wpse_login_page_blogname( $value ) {
    // Log in
    remove_filter( 'option_blogname', 'wpse_login_page_blogname', 10, 1 );
    return 'This is the changed blog name for the login page.';
}

function wpse_login_page_register_blogname( $value ) {
    // Register
    remove_filter( 'option_blogname', 'wpse_login_page_register_blogname', 10, 1 );
    return 'This is the changed blog name for the register page.';
}

function wpse_login_page_password_blogname( $value ) {
    // Reset password
    remove_filter( 'option_blogname', 'wpse_login_page_password_blogname', 10, 1 );
    return 'This is the changed blog name for the password reset page.';
}
```

Finally, these are the filters that will modify the `$title` portion of the title tag for each of the `wp-login.php` actions.

```
/**
 * Translate the $title portion of the <title>'s text on the wp-login.php page.
 * Immediately remove the filters so that they only run once.
 *
 * @param string $translation  Translated text.
 * @param string $text         Text to translate.
 * @param string $domain       Text domain. Unique identifier for retrieving translated strings.
 *
 * @return string
 */
function wpse_login_page_title( $translation, $text, $domain ) {
    // Log in
    // The 'default' text domain is reserved for the WP core.
    if ( 'default' === $domain && 'Log In' === $text ) {
        $translation = 'This is the changed "Log In" text.';
        remove_filter( 'gettext', 'wpse_login_page_title', 10, 3 );
    }
    return $translation;
}

function wpse_login_page_register_title( $translation, $text, $domain ) {
    // Register
    if ( 'default' === $domain && 'Registration Form' === $text ) {
        $translation = 'This is the changed "Registration Form" text.';
        remove_filter( 'gettext', 'wpse_login_page_register_title', 10, 3 );
    }
    return $translation;
}

function wpse_login_page_password_title( $translation, $text, $domain ) {
    // Reset password
    if ( 'default' === $domain && 'Lost Password' === $text ) {
        $translation = 'This is the changed "Lost Password" text.';
        remove_filter( 'gettext', 'wpse_login_page_password_title', 10, 3 );
    }
    return $translation;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions. It seems we're stuck with the {Sitename} {Sep} {Title} format but at least we can filter the various parts (aside from the separator).