# Function like is_registration_page to check if current page is registration page

Tags: user-registration, signup, wp-signup

You can use [`is_admin`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin) to check to see if the current web page is part of WordPress' administrator interface.

Is there a way to see if the page being processed is the registration page?

Comment: Are you asking about this page: wp-login.php?action=register or is there a custom registration page you're referring to.

Comment: That sounds right to me, although I've noticed that `$GLOBAS["pagenow"]` is `index.php` on the registration page. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: [Here's an answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/269448/2807) I posted a while back that may help. It demonstrates how to detect if the visitor is on the Registration, Password reset, or Log in page and then how to wire up filters. Specifically, I'm thinking the conditional statements used to detect what wp-login.php variant is being used might be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You could create your own simple function.

```
function is_registration_page() {
    if ( $GLOBALS['pagenow'] == 'wp-login.php' && isset($_REQUEST['action']) && $_REQUEST['action'] == 'register' ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about attempting to intercept the registration page via hooks. Here's an example of how hooks can be used to add a field to the registration form (below)... Depending on your situation, you can use this (and the hook to intercept a submitted form) as a means to achieve what you're looking for.

I added in a line:     $GLOBALS['is_registration'] = TRUE;

But note, this global variable may not be available at the point you require it. You will have to test to see.

```
<?php
add_action( 'register_form', 'myplugin_add_registration_fields' );
function myplugin_add_registration_fields() {

    $GLOBALS['is_registration'] = TRUE;

    //Get and set any values already sent
    $user_extra = ( isset( $_POST['user_extra'] ) ) ? $_POST['user_extra'] : '';
?>
    <label for="user_extra"><?php _e( 'Extra Field', 'myplugin_textdomain' ) ?>
    <input type="text" name="user_extra" id="user_extra" class="input" value="<?php echo esc_attr( stripslashes( $user_extra ) ); ?>" size="25" /></label>
<?php
}
?>
```

You can read more about these action/filter hooks at:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/register_form