# Change the - WordPress from titlebar?

Tags: customization

I use this code to edit the titlebar in the admin pages:

```
add_filter('admin_title', 'my_admin_title', 10, 2);

function my_admin_title($admin_title, $title)
{
return 'Example.com'.' &bull; '.$title.' &lsaquo; '.get_bloginfo('name'); 
}
```

Which works great, but I still can't figure out how to do the same with the title bar which appears on the Log in / Registration in the frontend.

Comment: You can try this link: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/269439/how-to-change-the-wp-login-php-page-title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you mysticalghoul.

This was the answer:

```
function custom_login_title( $login_title ) {
return str_replace(array( ' &lsaquo;', ' &#8212; WordPress'), array( ' &bull;', ' what ever you want'),$login_title );
}
add_filter( 'login_title', 'custom_login_title' );
```