# Restrict wordpress access to logged users only

Tags: php, functions, login

I want to limit the access to a wordpress app only to registered users.

I've putted this inside the function file, but I'm able to see the home also if I'm not logged in. How I fix this?

```
if( is_home() || is_page() || is_single() && !is_user_logged_in() ){
    wp_safe_redirect( wp_login_url() );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works only for blog pages, pages, and single posts. You need to disable redirection on the login page. Here you can find how to detect the login page. [Check if wp-login is current page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12863/check-if-wp-login-is-current-page)

So to redirect globally as you want use:

```
if(!is_user_logged_in() && !is_wplogin() ) wp_safe_redirect( wp_login_url() );
```

Function is_wplogin() is from here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/237285/181863

I also prefer to do redirection after init:

```
function is_wplogin(){
    $ABSPATH_MY = str_replace(array('\\','/'), DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, ABSPATH);
    return ((in_array($ABSPATH_MY.'wp-login.php', get_included_files()) || in_array($ABSPATH_MY.'wp-register.php', get_included_files()) ) || (isset($_GLOBALS['pagenow']) && $GLOBALS['pagenow'] === 'wp-login.php') || $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']== '/wp-login.php');
}

add_action('init', function () {
    if (!is_user_logged_in() && !is_wplogin()) {
        wp_redirect(wp_login_url());
        die();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`is_home()` is for the page that [shows the recent blog posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/).

If you have set a static page as front page, then that check doesn't return `true` there. Add a check for [`is_front_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/) to cover that case.

Comment: I get a redirect error now. I've removed the conditional tags, but I'm not able to see the login screen I get: `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`